# Jquery find next input element with a span between get undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" width="40" size="9">
<span name="foo"></span>
<input type="password" name="password" width="40" size="9">
```

I would like to get the next input element name when clicking on the username and that what I did:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    var NextElement = $(e.target).next().attr("name"); //return foo
});
```

But, I'm getting "foo" , and I actually want the next input element so I did:

```
    var NextElement = $(e.target).next("input").attr("name"); // return undefined
```

As I expected to get "password", this one returns "undefined".

see a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBWdh/) demo of this peoblem.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextAll()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/KBWdh/2/

```
var NextElement = $(e.target).nextAll("input").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 2):

As `next` only checks for the immediate following element, there's no direct function but you can do this:

```
var NextElement = $(e.target).nextUntil("input").last().next().attr("name");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/aqDtu/)

Usually I would find another solution to not rely on elements order, like for example a data attribute giving the id of the relevant element. Apart of course if the order is really what determines the element to get.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, why not just use nextAll() method?

Comment: it works, but if there is no <span> then it's getting undefine

Comment: @roasted nextAll returns a set of elements. As `attr` returns the attribute value of the first element it works but it's not clean in my opinion (and I didn't think to use this property of attr). Alternativaly nextAll('input').first() would have been a solution.

Comment: ya, i was thinking about it. Thx dystroy

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var NextElement = $(e.target).find("input:password").attr("name");
```

Since, click event is added to the `document`, we need to find the input in the `document`, `next()` method would not work here, as you would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

next() will return the next sibling, doesnt matter what you put in the parenthesis. Or as the docs say:

***If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.***

Use `.next().next()` or `nextAll()`

```
var NextElement = $(e.target).nextAll("input").filter(':first').attr("name");
```